# Scripting batch text mangling

Tags: text-processing

I often find myself trying to do trivial text manipulations on quite large files. It seems like there ought to be a way to script this with one or other of the various Unix text mangling tools, but I can't figure out how exactly.

As a concrete example, suppose I have some source code that looks like this:

```
foo1 = undefined
foo2 = undefined
foo3 = foobar 7
foo4 = undefined
```

And I want to transform it to look like this:

```
foo1 = error "foo1"
foo2 = error "foo2"
foo3 = foobar 7
foo4 = error "foo4"
```

It *looks like* there ought to be some way in hell to do this transformation automatically. Obviously I can easily *write a program* in a real programming language. But surely there's some command-line tool that can do this. (?)

As a more complex example, how do I turn

```
foo=ABC
bar=DEF
baz=GHI
foo=123
bar=456
baz=789
```

into

```
Magic(ABC, DEF, GHI);
Magic(123, 456, 789);
```

More generally, which tool should I be looking at to do these sorts of transformations? Is that `sed`, or `awk`, or...?

Comment: What are the criteria for grouping *Magic*? Alpha vs, Numeric?  Groupings of foo, bar, baz? Both? In groups of 3?  Does the sequence matter? Are there likely to be *non-Magic* lines? ... really it dosn't matter that much if you are primarily interested in what app to use.. The answer to that is `awk`.  `sed` is very good for simple text manipulation, but `awk` is the one when you need to do some serious juggling.

Comment: @Peter.O All good questions. It's one particular example of something I needed to do. The lines will always be `foo` followed by `bar` followed by `baz`, possibly with intervening lines that I don't care about. `foo` should always become the first argument to `Magic()`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the particular situation.  Your first example could resolved using either `sed` or `awk`. For example, using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
/undefined/ {printf "%s = error \"%s\"\n", $1, $1; next}
{print}
' input
```

Which produces:

```
foo1 = error "foo1"
foo2 = error "foo2"
foo3 = foobar 7
foo4 = error "foo4"
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed '
  /undefined/ s/\([^ ]*\) =.*/\1 = error "\1"/
' input
```

Your second example would probably be easier to do with `awk`, or some higher level language like Perl or Python. Again, with `awk`:

```
awk '
{
    split($0, parts, "=")
    items[i++] = parts[2]
}
i%3 == 0 {
    printf "Magic(%s, %s, %s)\n", items[0], items[1], items[2]
    i=0
}

' input
```

Which produces:

```
Magic(ABC, DEF, GHI)
Magic(123, 456, 789)
```

More generally...I'm not sure it's possible to provide a general answer.  It really depends on the specific task you're trying to accomplish.  Once you've pulled out `awk` you're already *writing a program* in a *real programming language*, so you shouldn't eschew a higher level tool (like Perl or Python or Ruby or whatever) just because it's more capable.

Comment: Your first `awk` example is outputting the original `undefined` line after it prints the modified version.

Comment: It's not, actually ( with `gawk` 4.1.1).

Comment: Ah, interesting. It does with *GNU Awk  3.1.6*

Comment: I have just tried it in *GNU Awk 4.0.1* and it too outputs 7 lines (instead of 4) - here is the actual code I used:  `printf '%s\n' 'foo1 = undefined' 'foo2 = undefined' 'foo3 = foobar 7' 'foo4 = undefined' | awk '/undefined/ {printf "%s = error \"%s\"\n", $1, $1} {print}'` ...

Comment: So for general "cut this text here, paste it there", `awk` is the puppy to use? You got any good references for learning about it? All the tutorials I could find only cover trivial 1-liners, and don't go into the syntax for larger blocks of code...

Comment: @larsks: GNU Awk 4.1.1 in Ubuntu-Mate (in a freshly installed VM) prints the same 7 lines of output as v3.1.5 and v4.0.1 - ie. it prints 3 unwanted `foo? = undefined` lines - I can't see how you would be getting only 4 lines output - it needs a `next` to skip the `{print}.

Comment: There, all better.   Embarassing GIGO problem. Don't run `sed -i` when producing demos.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is great for simple text manipulation - typically single-line edits, though it can work with multi-lines (with a lot of effort). Overall `sed` is rather hamstrung, by the lack of variables and arithemtic calculations, but nonetheless it does offer the simplest solution in many instances.

`awk` is very effective for both simple and complex manipulation of text and numberic calculations, but it is not ideally suitable for things beyond that.

For the first example:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]+) = undefined$/\1 = error "\1"/' file1
```

```
awk '$3=="undefined"{ $3="error \"" $1 "\"" } {print $0}' file1
```

For the second example, based on =*values* being either all-UPPERCASE alpha, or all-NUMERIC. It also groups any non-Magic lines (to remove, just delete `out[0]` statements):

```
awk -F'=' 'BEGIN{ # split regular expressions, using `x7F` as delimiter (or any char not in the regex)  
                  n=split("^[A-Z]+$" "\x7F" "^[0-9]+$",rx,"\x7F") 
           } 
           { for( i=1;i<=n;i++ ){
                 if( $2 ~ rx[i] ){ 
                     out[i]=out[i] sprintf( (out[i] ?", " :"") "%s", $2)
                     break 
             }   } 
             if( i>n ) out[0]=out[0] $0 RS # non-matching lines 
           }
           END{ printf out[0]
                for( i=1;i<=n;i++ ){ print "Magic(" out[i] ")" }
           }' file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl, as it is a (reasonably "normal") programming language, built around powerful text manipulation (search, replace in vi(1) style with regular expressions). But many would consider me a heretic, and use Python instead. Both are distributed with any Linux distribution and have decent Windows implementations (and I'm sure for Mac too). Python has the advantage that it is use to build much of the GUI for administration tools in e.g. Fedora, so it should be alredy installed.

`awk(1)` and `sed(1)` are powerful tools, but somewhat single-minded...